# Issue with doParallel and foreach. I can register cores, but they don't seem to run

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, hpc, doparallel

I have a large data set (about 40 million rows x 4 columns) and I want to perform a Fisher test on the data in each row.

An example of the data looks like this:

```
refAppleBase altAppleBase refHawBase altHawBase
1          115            1         94          0
2          117            4         93          1
3          125            4         94          1
4          107           26         89         12
5           87           53         66         38
6           68           58         64         32
```

I have written the following script that essentially takes each row, converts into a matrix so it can run on the base `fisher.test()` function in R, and then spits out the odds ratio and p-value.

```
fisher.odds.pval <- function(table){ 
fisher <- fisher.test(matrix(unlist(table), nrow=2, ncol=2))
p.val <- fisher$p.value
odds <- unname(fisher$estimate)
return(cbind(odds, p.val))
}
```

Now, obviously this a little clunky and I want to run it across 40 million rows, so to save time, I wrote the following script, using the `foreach` and `doParallel` packages to parallelize this across multiple cores.

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)
results <- foreach(i=1:nrow(dat)) %dopar% {
  fisher.odds.pval(table=dat[i,])
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

I have used `doParallel`in the past to great success. However, when running the above script, I can see the cores "wake up" and load in data, but then immediately go to sleep. Then it seems that just one core is doing all of the computing. Here is a screen grab of `top`, when the above code is running.

[top screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChQQt.png)

Note: When I run the above script on a smaller dataset using `%do%` instead of `%dopar%` it works, so I suspect there something fishy going on between the way `foreach` and `doParallel` are communicating? But really lost here right now. Any thought greatly appreciated.

Comment: One potential speed up is to convert dat to a matrix once outside of your function and then transpose. R stores matrices by column, so subsetting by column should be a lot faster given your data size.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am replicating the same behavior on Windows. The function `makeCluster()` belongs to the `parallel` package and their back-end for parallelization, which is distinct from `doParallel`'s back-end. This will work with `snow` and their parallel functions `clusterApply()`, etc.

If you go straight to `registerDoParallel(cl = 10)`, or `registerDoParallel(cores = 10)`, it will register the `doParallel` back-end for use with `foreach()` -- my system shows proper allocation on all cores this way using your function and data.

To stop the workers, use `registerDoSEQ()`. To show number of workers initialized, use `getDoParWorkers()`

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct use of `registerDoSEQ()`. Many (many) comments on stackoverflow assume that `makeCluster()` is necessary for `doParallel` and that `stopCluster()` will terminate parallel clusters with `doParallel`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that, if you're using Windows, R has to transfer `dat` to each cluster (which is slow and uses a lot of memory).
One possible solution would be to use shared memory (more info [there](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/)).

#### Reproducible data

```
df <- read.table(text = "refAppleBase altAppleBase refHawBase altHawBase
1          115            1         94          0
                 2          117            4         93          1
                 3          125            4         94          1
                 4          107           26         89         12
                 5           87           53         66         38
                 6           68           58         64         32")
dat <- df[rep(1:4, 1e7), ] 

fisher.odds.pval <- function(table){ 
  fisher <- fisher.test(matrix(unlist(table), nrow=2, ncol=2))
  p.val <- fisher$p.value
  odds <- unname(fisher$estimate)
  return(cbind(odds, p.val))
}
```

#### Your current solution (uses lot of memory!!)

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(10))
results <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
  fisher.odds.pval(table=dat[i,])
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

#### One solution using shared memory

```
library(doParallel)
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
fbm <- bigstatsr::as_FBM(dat, type = "integer")
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(10))
results2 <- foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% {
  fisher.odds.pval(table=fbm[i,])
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that you will gain more by optimizing (e.g. vectorizing) the sequential version, instead of directly relying on parallelism.